# How to download a file from url and save to FTP

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I am trying to download a file from url and save it to my ftp server however it throughs error of invalid character in path

```
using (var wc = new WebClient())
{
wc.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(Properties.Settings.Default.FTP_Username, Properties.Settings.Default.FTP_Password);
var savedAs= new Uri(ftp_IP + ftp_directory + miscellaneous.filename);
wc.DownloadFile(new Uri(miscellaneous.fulldownloadLink), savedAs);

}
```

Comment: put your code inside try/catch and print the exception and post the output here. It will help you and us understand what is causing the problem.

Comment: Also print out the path that you are trying to save it to, full path.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot save to an ftp:// Uri as you are trying to do. `WebClient.DownloadFile` can only save to a local file (i.e.: a file residing on the local computer).

> `public void DownloadFile (Uri address, string fileName);`
>
> **Parameters**
>
> *address* Uri
>
> The URI specified as a String, from which to download data.
>
> *fileName* String
>
> The name of the **local file** that is to receive the data.

REF: [WebClient.DownloadFile Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.downloadfile)